# Favorites saving on backend, but against all users not the current user logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, controller, jwt, fetch

I am creating an app where one of the functionalities is to make it so that the current user logged in can save a coffee shop to their favorites list.  Right now my favorites are currently working, however when it saves on the backend it saves against all users not just the current user logged in.  Im using a rails backend with JWT Auth and React frontend. I attempted to correct this by doing something like this in my FavoritesController...

```
....
 def index
        favorites = Favorite.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
        render json: favorites
    end
```

and then on the front end trying to grab the user_id in my GET and POST request such as;

Get Request ...

```
...
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorites?user_id=${user_id}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(favorites => this.setState({ favorites }))
    }
```

Container ...

```
import React from 'react';
import CoffeeShop from './CoffeeShop'
import NavBar from './NavBar'

class CafesContainer extends React.Component {

  state = {
    cafes: [],
    cafe:{},
    isCafeViewOn: false,
    inputValue: '',
    inputSort: '',
    user: {
      id:0,
      username:'',
      token:'',
    }
}

...

addToFav = (cafe) => {
  console.log(cafe)
  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorites?user_id=${user_id}`,{
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `bearer ${localStorage.token}`
    },
      body: JSON.stringify( cafe )
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
  }

 ...
  
render() {  
  
...

      <input type="text" className="cafe-search-bar" placeholder="Type Cafe Name Here..." value={this.inputValue} onChange={(e) => {this.cafeFilterOnChange(e)}}/>

      <ul>
        {
           filteredCafes.map(cafe => <CoffeeShop cafes={this.filteredCafes} handleCafeView={this.handleCafeView} cafeFilterOnChange={this.cafeFilterOnChange} inputValue={this.inputValue}
           addToFav={this.addToFav} key={cafe.id} cafe={cafe} />)
        }  
      </ul>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
;
  export default CafesContainer;
```

However when I try to do his way against by fetching the user_id and posting with the user_id I get a error on the frontend stating

```
'user_id' is not defined  no-undef
```

from what im gathering its not getting the state of the user even tho im setting at the top in state, im able to get this to work if I do something like this

```
   componentDidMount() {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorites`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(favorites => this.setState({ favorites }))
    }

...

addToFav = (cafe) => {
  console.log(cafe)
  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorites`,{
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `bearer ${localStorage.token}`
    },
      body: JSON.stringify( cafe )
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
  }
```

but this is setting it for all users not just the current user logged in..

Any advise would be great!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find where are you calling the index method to get the list of favorites of a certain user but wherever that is you have to pass the user ID as a param. something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/favorites?user_id=${user_id}
```

I would also recommend adding a .sort at the end of the query in the controller so that you can control the logic of how the list of favorites appear (date added to favorites, cafe name, etc).

Comment: So i need to fetch the favorites first and then post to the back end? something like this ... ```componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorites?user_id=${user_id}`)
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(favorites => this.setState({ favorites }))
}
```  and then attempt to post? Im still getting the user_id error, even after adding in ```http://localhost:3000/favorites?user_id=${user_id}```

Comment: You are talking about two different operations. If you have to show the user's favorites you have to GET /favorites with a user_id. Separately, if you want to add a new favorite you do a POST /favorites. GET /favorites will route you to def index and POST /favorites will take you to create. Regarding the error, are you getting the error in rails or react? after the GET or after the POST?

Comment: Check the helper user because probably you are getting the error on the line  favorite.user_id = @user.id. The logs should say in which line you are getting the error

Comment: thanks for your help so far.  Sorry I should be more clear, I did make a GET request for the favorites with ```componentDidMount() {   fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorites?user_id=${user_id}`)   .then(resp => resp.json())   .then(favorites => this.setState({ favorites })) }``` and then i attempted to post them with my addFav function above.  The error that I get is on both the GET request and the addFav stating it can not get the user_id in the requests.  This error is happening on the front end in React.

Comment: update, I have had success getting it to work again but its only doing it against all users and not the current one logged in....ive updated the initial question

Comment: Did you check on rails logs what params are you getting? Check again the helper @user because apparently that is where you are supposed to be getting the user. Probably you shouldn't even pass user_id as a param for security reasons and instead rely on the "@ user" to get the user for you so that a user cannot get someone else's data